# does string.length calculate length on calling string.length

Tags: javascript, string, time-complexity

Recently i came to know the time complexity for string.length in javascript is 0(1). is there any one who can make me understand why as to get the length we need to go through all the characters and if the string having n characters then it should depend on the n and should cost us 0(n).

I would really appreciate if someone can clear this or can send link for the native implementation of string.length

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Strings are immutable. The length is known when the string is introduced into the runtime, either via the source code itself or from some environmental API (like the DOM). It never changes, so it's simply stored internally with the value.

Comment: aaah it calculates length and attach this as property when we create string and we are only fetching value when we do string.length that's why it has 0(1) right or did i miss something @Pointy

Comment: Right, the interpreter simply retains the string length internally. Well, it doesn't *have* to do that; there's no explicit mandate in the language spec, but no modern interpreter would not implement strings any other way (or at least I'd be very surprised).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String is a class. A class can have member variables and functions. When you create a string the length member variable is  probably set. There's probably a "hidden" function that runs O(n) for the initialising of the string but once the length is set, the computer need only access the value, so O(1). This is all predefined and the programmer need only know how to use the function.

Comment: It's true that String is a class, but a constant like `"hello world"` does **not** create an instance of the String class; it creates a string primitive value.

Comment: @Pointy ah of course you're more right

Answer (score 2):

This is because string is immutable,so the length is calculated when string is created and it will never change.

When a string is modified, a new string object will be created and so length.

So length is constant time `O(1)`.